# How to mute the state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, state-management, react-state-management

I am having a issue in reactjs state management .Everytime component loaded it loads the data from cache.I done research over that and found that state is immutable.I want to ask how to use immute the state.
Currently it is like i took a empty array in state in constructor then I called a api in component will mount and set that state to response but untill and unless Indont clear cache, state is not showing the data

Guide me where I am making mistake here or how can I immute the state

Comment: Hard to say without looking at some code. But in general, if you want to change the state, simply set it to an empty string or something else of your choosing so the data that is pulling from the state does not get loaded from the change

Comment: that's the issue data is not loading after setstate, data is loading after cache clear

Comment: without code or example we can't help, and btw state should be treated as "immutable", but still I am confused what do you mean by `unmute` the state. do you mean rollback the data ?

Comment: Pardon changed the question.Have a look

Comment: well I think you are asking why `this.state = xxx` is not working ?

Comment: yupp its working after cache clearing

Answer (score 0):

**Mutating an object: Use the Object.assign({}, ...)**

```
var yourCar = {
color: 'red',
.. the same as neighboursCar
};

var neighboursCar = {
 color: 'red',
... the same as yourCar
};

yourCar.color = 'blue'; // reference stays the same!

var yourCarRepainted = Object.assign({}, yourCar, { color: 'blue' });

yourCarRepainted === yourCar; // false
```

**Mutating an array: Use [].concat**

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list = [1, 2, 3];
list[1] = 4;

var list = [1, 2, 3];
var changedList = [].concat(list);
changedList[1] = 4;

var list = [1, 2, 3];
var changedList = [].concat(list);
changedList[1] = 2;

list === changedList; // false
```

**this.state and this.setState({})** in React is already immutable.

*You can also try immutable.js 3rd party library to get a better grasp on this subject.*